# share mongodb between nodejs and meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I just finished a REST server application in nodejs using express, passport and mongodb

I want to create a meteor app for the LIVE Statistics of that mongodb REST api's , like number of connections, user online etc.

But I can't figure out a way to use custom mongodb with meteor. Basically I want to share the same database with nodejs/express application and meteor.

Is it possible? I am sure it should be, but I can't figure out HOW!

Help please!

Comment: see my answer, deploying it on nodejs server will let me choose which database to use.

Comment: Well done - remember to mark as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I got here what to do.

While deploying meteor, they have an option to choose the database.

So i created an app on meteor and then deployed it for nodejs

here is how,

meteor bundle myapp.tgz

extracted myapp.tgz and used the command below.

PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js

Here is complete doc : http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying